# Page not displaying in Doxygen documentation

Tags: doxygen, chm

I am making an API documentation via Doxygen in which I have created an .md file that has some list in it first and some sub-pages.

When I compile the documentation in CHM file it shows those sub-pages under the same filename but when I click on the filename it doesn't show any page, whereas after clicking on the same filename under the menu bar, it shows 'This page can't be displayed' just like in IE.

Please let me know the solution, regarding the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Please add the code snippet of your MarkDown file to see how the sub-pages are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple linked markdown files may cause the described behavior. But you have not clearly described how these ***.md** files are used.

For a compiled CHM help file all links must work from the HTML files generated by Doxygen before compiling the ***.hhp** file by e.g HTML Help Workshop.

Everything works as expected when using links to example web pages. I added a **README.md** to reproduce in a test project.

```
Linking from Doxygen using MarkDown
===================================

[HelpMVP]: http://www.helpmvp.com/  "Help MVP"
[HelpwareGroupDE]: http://www.help-info.de/en/FAR/far_support.htm  "Help Info"

For building CHM's with FAR HTML have a look at [HelpMVP] and [HelpWareGroupDE].

[This link shows a web site topic inside of the CHM's help viewer content pane: ](http://www.help-info.eu/en/FAR/far.htm)

<!-- simple use HTML syntax in a MarkDown file to open in a new window -->
<a href="http://www.help-info.eu/en/FAR/far.htm" target="_blank">This link shows a web site topic in a new window by using HTML syntax as markdown!</a>
```

After running Doxygen and compiling a CHM (in my case using FAR HTML) this is resulting in the help viewer like shown in the snapshot below. The topic is reachable from **Related Pages** too. Please note and try for your needs - two kind of links are used in my sample:

1. shows a web site topic inside of the CHM's help viewer content pane
2. or simple use HTML syntax in a MarkDown file to open in a new window

For further information have a look at the Doxygen specifics [Including Markdown files as pages](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_page_header).

[image]